# ConsumerIrManager object is null

Tags: java, android

I defined ConsumerIrManager as following:

```
ConsumerIrManager irManager = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
```

But for some reason it is `null` and I can't use functions like .transmit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not guaranteed to get the service. There are multiple cases which can lead to `null` you are facing, starting from most obvious one, which is lack of hardware support for IR on the device to missing `android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR` permission declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file. I'd also inspect logcat and look for any related warning or error.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what was needed!